# build docker image with dockerfile by jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile

I've been blocked since yesterday and need some help. I tried to use both `jenkins docker-plugin` and `docker-plugin-step` to build docker image from a dockerfile.

However, when I try to run the jenkins job, it gives me the following exception:

```
Docker Build
Docker Build : build with tag jdubois/jhipster-docker:Gateway_Jenkins_V1 at path /home/javateam/DockerfileGateway
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: config was not specified
    at shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:226)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.<init>(DockerClientImpl.java:36)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.getInstance(DockerClientImpl.java:52)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(DockerClientBuilder.java:29)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.builder.DockerBuilderPublisher$Run$1.invoke(DockerBuilderPublisher.java:144)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.builder.DockerBuilderPublisher$Run$1.invoke(DockerBuilderPublisher.java:139)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.builder.DockerBuilderPublisher$Run.buildImage(DockerBuilderPublisher.java:139)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.builder.DockerBuilderPublisher$Run.run(DockerBuilderPublisher.java:89)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.builder.DockerBuilderPublisher.perform(DockerBuilderPublisher.java:180)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:915)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:866)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Build / Publish Docker Containers' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The following is the dockerfile content:

```
#Basic images for Gateway MS
FROM jdubois/jhipster-docker:Gateway_Jenkins_V1

#Fetch last Gateway MS version from gitlab and run it
RUN cd /home/jhipster/DockerJenkinsGateway && \
git pull origin master

# expose the working directory, the Tomcat port, the BrowserSync ports, the SSHD port, and run SSHD
VOLUME ["/jhipster"]
EXPOSE 8080 3000 3001 22
CMD    /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

What am doing wrong??

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile? Without it it is uneasy to guess.

Comment: #Basic images for Gateway MS:    
`FROM jdubois/jhipster-docker:Gateway_Jenkins_V1`

#Fetch last Gateway MS version from gitlab and run it:   
`RUN cd /home/jhipster/DockerJenkinsGateway && \
git pull origin master`

# expose the working directory, the Tomcat port, the BrowserSync ports, the SSHD port, and run SSHD:   
`VOLUME ["/jhipster"]`
`EXPOSE 8080 3000 3001 22`
`CMD    /usr/sbin/sshd -D`

Comment: When folks ask for additional information, please update your *question* rather than pasting it as a comment, because as you can see comments do not permit formatting of preformatted text, making it very difficult to read (also, take a minute to read the documentation about properly formatting preformatted text -- like your dockerfile -- in the question).

Comment: this looks like a configuration problem with the Jenkins plugin. The underlying `docker-java` library checks for the presence of a `DockerClientConfig` which seems to be null. It might even be a missing config in your Maven pom.xml.

Comment: There is no relation between dockerfile configuration under jenkins and pom.xml content !!! @gesellix

Comment: I added for you the dockerfile content @larsks

Comment: nevertheless there seems to be a missing `DockerClientConfig`... I suggest to check your plugin config, see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin#DockerPlugin-Configuration @mootez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the shell provided by Jenkins as a build step, and just build the Docker image using the command-line arguments you would normally use in that shell script.

That's what we do on our build server and it gives us fine grained control over things like versioning and which image/tag to push to Dockerhub.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that's just what i did. but jenkins community have to develop plugins doing this important kind of stuffs.

Comment: Yeah, as I understand it the difficulty is to do with pushing a large number of tags/knowing which tags to push, which is why some of these don't work so well. Just on my laptop I've caused errors before by trying to push say ten tags or so. Might be other things too, but that's the one that springs to mind!

Comment: the docs for this jenkins plugin in particular are absolutely horrible. one of the key config fields (that blocks if you don't fill it in correctly) has the following helpful dialog when you click on the help icon : "TODO: Docker REST API endpoint help"

Comment: @Petrov: did you ever figure out how to configure that field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jenkins 2.0 or above then Jenkins give you an option to build pipeline as the code and you can easily integrate docker and its repositories.

Go to --> new item --> select multi branch pipeline option and you will see the option to connect to docker via Jenkins.

Let me know in case of more details.